# How to run the GUI of Windows Features On/Off using Powershell

Tags: powershell, administration

Yes, the question is as the title said. It seem weird since we can invoke it using the Start Menu. But my PC is a client one and I was in an Administrative PowerShell session and would like to run it from there to see which features my PC had.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the command `optionalfeatures` in CMD and PowerShell to open the old styled feature dialog.
[image]

---

To output/pipe/use it in the shell you can use `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online`
[image]

---

If you mean the Windows Capabilities you can use the PowerShell command `Get-WindowsCapability -Online`
[image]

---

There's a good summary of many those commands and shell extensions on the following pages, but it's in German:

- [Executing Shell Commands](https://www.deskmodder.de/wiki/index.php?title=Ausf%C3%BChren_Shell_Commands)
- [Shortcuts to system tools, control panel, etc.](https://www.deskmodder.de/wiki/index.php?title=Verlinkungen_zu_Systemtools_,Systemsteuerung_etc.)